# Cannot split input from `Scanner`

Tags: java, split, java.util.scanner

```java
String command = scanner.next();
String[] split = command.split(" ");
System.out.println(split.length);
```

Hello, anyone knows why it gives me the length 1 back when I insert `"a b c d e f g h i"` ?

Comment: Use a debugger (or print) to see the contents of `command`.

Answer (score 0):

`next()` reads the input till the space (`" "`), so the variable `command` will be `"a"` instead of  `"a b c d e f g h i"`

You should use `nextLine()` that reads the input including space between the letters:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String command = scanner.nextLine();
String[] split = command.split(" ");
System.out.println(split.length);
```

For more information, take a look at [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--).

Answer (score 0):

You are only retrieving the a in your line and not the full line use String command = scanner.nextLine(); instead.

Answer (score 0):

`next()` and `nextLine()` methods are two different methods with Scanner for getting String inputs.

`next()` can read the input only till the space. It can't read two words separated by space. Also, `next()` places the cursor in the same line after reading the input.

`nextLine()` reads input including space between the words (that is, it reads till the end of line \n). Once the input is read, `nextLine()` positions the cursor in the next line.

So here you should use `nextLine()` rather than `next()`.